# Disable up and down arrow buttons on JSpinner

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I have a JSpinner on which I would like to take control of when editing is enabled.  It's easy enough with the keyboard, but how about those little arrow widgets at the side?  I can't even find references to them in the JSpinner source or any of its enclosed classes.

Comment: What is wrong with the functionality provided by `JSpinner#setEnabled` ? I do not see how this would be different from disabling the textfield editor and the arrow buttons

Comment: Probably nothing, and why didn't I think of that, but really, I'm still curious where they've hidden these buttons.

Comment: Those buttons are contained in the `SpinnerUI` class. See for example the `BasicSpinnerUI` class where you can override the `createNextButton` method, meaning you have access to those buttons

Comment: there are two BasicArrowButton, is possible to re_layout, disable, change/replace these Components, change Icon, I'd be to change Icon from black to red

Answer (score 4):

You can use `setUI()` method to hide Jspinner arrow.

```
public void hideSpinnerArrow(JSpinner spinner) {
        Dimension d = spinner.getPreferredSize();
        d.width = 30;
        spinner.setUI(new BasicSpinnerUI() {
            protected Component createNextButton() {
                return null;
            }

            protected Component createPreviousButton() {
                return null;
            }
        });
        spinner.setPreferredSize(d);
    }
```

As you see, just make `createNextButton()` and `createPreviousButton()` return `null`.

Because we used a BasicUI so we have to setup Spinner size again. I used `PreferredSize`.

Answer (score 0):

you can't take control of these two arrow buttons but you can do like this

```
    private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                  

          p.setEnabled(false);

}
```

suppose you want a button pressed and the user will not able to use jspinner at all this is a hint for more actions you can modified it as well

Answer (score 0):

you can also allow use to use the jspinner untill for a specific value using

```
   if(spinner.getValue()==10){
       //show error message and 
       spinner.setEnabled(false);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the UI class used derives from `BasicSpinnerUI`, the arrow buttons can be removed with:

```
    for (Component component : spinner.getComponents()) {
        if (component.getName() != null && component.getName().endsWith("Button")) {
            spinner.remove(component);
        }
    }
```